# optimizing recursive function performance (euler 15: lattice paths)

Tags: haskell, recursion, memoization

I'm trying to solve project eulers 15th problem, lattice paths (http://projecteuler.net/problem=15).

My first attempt was to solve the problem line by line and then taking the last element in the last line.

```
number_of_ways_new_line last_line = foldl calculate_values [] last_line
                                    where
                                      calculate_values lst x = lst ++ [(if length lst > 0 then (last lst) + x else head last_line)]

count_ways x = foldl (\ lst _ -> number_of_ways_new_line lst) (take x [1,1..]) [1..x-1]

result_15 = last $ count_ways 21
```

This works and is fast, but I think it is really ugly. So I thought about it for a while and came up with a more idiomatic function (please correct me if I get this wrong), that sovles the problem using recursion:

```
lattice :: Int -> Int -> Int
lattice 0 0 = 1
lattice x 0 = lattice (x-1) 0
lattice 0 y = lattice (y-1) 0
lattice x y
  | x >= y    = (lattice (x-1) y) + (lattice x (y-1))
  | otherwise = (lattice y (x-1)) + (lattice (y-1) x)
```

This works good for short numbers, but it doesn't scale at all. I optimized it a little bit by using the fact that `lattice 1 2` and `lattice 2 1` will always be the same. Why is this so slow? Isn't Haskell memoizing previous results, so that whenever `lattice 2 1` is called it remembers the old result?

Comment: This problem has very simple combinatorial answer.

Comment: It doesn't memoizing previous results. If you want to make your solution work you need to build up some array and call on its values recursively.

Comment: Have you ever heard of the infallible 80-column rule? You could do with that here. http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EightyColumnRule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now this problem can be solved mathematically be manipulating the recurrence relations into a closed form, but I'll focus on the more interesting problem, memoizing.

First we can use `Data.Array` (this is the lazy one)

```
 import Data.Array as A

 lattice x y = array ((0, 0), (x, y)) m ! (x, y)
   where m = [(,) (x, y) (lattice' x y) | x <- [0..x], y <- [0..y]
         lattice' 0 0  = 1
         lattice' x 0 = lattice (x-1) 0
         lattice' 0 y = lattice (y-1) 0
         lattice' x y | x >= y    = (lattice (x-1) y) + (lattice x (y-1))
                      | otherwise = (lattice y (x-1)) + (lattice (y-1) x)
```

Now these recurrences go through the map, but, since the map is lazy, once a map entry is evaluated, it's thunk will be mutated to be a simple value ensuring it's only ever computed once.

We can also use the wonderful `memo-combinators` library.

```
 import Data.MemoCombinators as M
 lattice = memo2 M.integral M.integral lattice'
   where lattice' 0 0 = 1
         lattice' x 0 = lattice (x-1) 0
         lattice' 0 y = lattice (y-1) 0
         lattice' x y | x >= y    = lattice (x-1) y + lattice x (y-1)
                      | otherwise = lattice y (x-1) + lattice (y-1) x
```

Comment: Does that mean, that in Haskell there is no memoization at all for simple functions, and it is only achieved by applying the function to the next value in some lazy list?

Comment: @sra Haskell doesn't memoize because it's just too memory intensive. It does share function arguments (eg, call by name with sharing) but that's it

Comment: It's not memoized by applying functions in a lazy list, but by filling an array so that each value is dependent on previous values in the array, this way, laziness ensures each is computed exactly once.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking that the function call will actually be 'replaced' by the value once the value is known. But your example with the lazy list makes perfect sense to me. I also like the fact that there is no 'outer scope' object needed (even if it would be hidden) for the caching.

Comment: @sra No problem, if you like my answer, feel free to accept it :) I also recommend using memo-combinators, It's very pleasant to use and very reliable.

Comment: I will definitely catchup on memo-combinators. The solution seems much more pretty.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is indeed slow, because it depends on multiple recursions at the same time.

Let's examine the `lattice` function. What does it do? It returns either the sum of two `lattice`functions, another `lattice` function, or the number one.

Now let's run down an example: `lattice 2 2`.
This equals `lattice 1 2 + lattice 2 1`.
This equals `lattice 0 2 + lattice 1 1 + lattice 1 1 + lattice 2 0`.
This equals ...

Do you realize the problem? There is not a single case of multiplication or adding a constant in your code. This means that the entire function will boil down to:

`1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + ... + 1`

This sum is your final result. However, every 1 in the above sum is the result of one or multiple function calls. So your function will be evaluated more often than the result is worth.

Now consider that `lattice 20 20` yields about 150 billion (it's an estimate, so I don't spoil too much).

This means your function gets evaluated around 150 000 000 000 times.

*Yikes.*

Don't feel bad for this mistake. I once said:

`fibbonaci x = fibbonaci (x-1) + fibbonaci (x-2)`

I encourage you to figure out why this is such a bad idea.

PS be glad they didn't ask for `lattice 40 40`. That would've taken more than 10^23 function calls, or at least 3 million years.

PPS your acceleration by calculating only one side will only slow down execution, as the amount of function calls doesn't decrease, however the time per function call will.

*disclaimer*: This is the first piece of Haskell code I've ever seen.